# Take a file path from commandline and use it in a "file" constructor?

Tags: java

I want my code to take a file path - C:\games\mario.txt (windows) or C:/games/mario.txt (linux). I want to use this path inside a "file" constructor like FileInputStream("");

If the path is windows style, then it needs to be modified by adding \ after every \, ie FileInputStream("C:\\games\\mario.txt");

Is there any API to validate such paths and then prepare them for use in a "file" constructor ?

Comment: If this is Java 7, forget `File`. Use `Files` and `Paths`!

Comment: You could, instead of using a slash literal, call the method `System.getProperty("file.separator")` which obtains and returns the OS-dependent file-separator string. (\ on Windows and / on Linux)

Comment: You don't need to do anything. Java on Windows will happily accept a forward slash as the path delimiter. So `C:/games/mario.txt` is a valid filename to Java (and the `File` class). There is nothing you need to change.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - thanks. makes sense. wonder what will happen if someone wanted to enter a path in windows style.

Comment: That will work just as well - at least on Windows. Haven't tried with Unix though

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [FileNameUtils#separatorsToSystem()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#separatorsToSystem%28java.lang.String%29). It is in Apache Commons API.

In Java 7 , you can make use of the [Paths](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html) class.

```
String path = Paths.get("C:/games/mario.txt").toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.getProperty("file.separator")` to know whether the underneath OS uses / or \ to separate paths.